# During the Trump administration, how did foreign states rank in engaging in personal diplomatic meetings with the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, european-union, donald-trump, international-relations

During the Trump administration, how did foreign states rank in engaging in diplomatic meetings with the U.S. in state visits, official visits, working visits, official working visits in the U.S. or being reciprocated by the U.S. in the foreign state?

In other words, which foreign state enjoyed how many of these visiting the U.S. and being visited by the U.S. respectively?

A narrower question could also be: How did EU Member States rank in the same regard under Trump?

Comment: The scale you are suggesting seems pretty arbitrary and the value in a meeting would have a different value depending on the size and power of each country.

Comment: @JoeW, The OP's scale is hypothetical and not necessary to the Q.  Obviously there have always been orders of precedence, whatever those happen to be now or have been in the past.

Comment: @agc maybe but how exactly do you rank diplomatic contact and that needs to be answered to answer this question

Comment: @JoeW, I'd assume there are texts like this, (only with more details and notes about relevant international idiosyncrasies): https://www.state.gov/protocol-reference/.  If that text is correct, then presumably any rankings would be a matter of agreement between the respective [Chiefs of Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_of_protocol) of the meeting heads of state and their ambassadors.

Comment: What's interesting about this Q. is that the topic is plainly political, but apparently is one of those rare political disciplines that is either so perfected, (or specialized), that it attracts virtually no public controversy or critique.  Like a black box that "just works"...

Comment: To close voters, this isn't a bad Q; there is even an official US ranking system for how foreign visits [to the US] are "ranked", although the OP was probably unware. https://www.rferl.org/a/1086035.html